# Copy trigger postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to copy from one table to another but if i try delete data from i have some problems "
The structure of the record "new" is not yet known" How i can fix that?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cops()
      RETURNS trigger
    AS $$
    BEGIN

      INSERT INTO people(id, region, space, alth, man, woman, year)
      VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.region, NEW.space, NEW.alth, NEW.man, NEW.woman, NEW.year);
      return NULL;

    END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    CREATE TRIGGER order_trigger AFTER INSERT OR  UPDATE OR  DELETE
    ON "tmp" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE kopia(); 

    delete from tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

For a delete statement there is no NEW values as you are only deleting. You will need to reference OLD. A separate trigger for DELETE and another for INSERT,UPDATE would be the way to go.